# multivariate Gaussian/normal distribution- sigma covariance and eigenvector

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

For a Multivariate Gaussian Distribution
[image: The formula of Multivariate Normal Distribution]
[image: The geometric properties]

I am a bit confused about the derivation of sigma
[image: Derivation of sigma]

[image: The deduction of sigma from Christopher Bishop's book- Pattern recognition and machine learning]

I am confused that I still cannot get the details of the derivation of sigma.

Could anyone help me with the process from having known $\Sigma u_i=\lambda_i u_i$ and $u_i $is orthonormal, to the result of $\Sigma=\sum^D_i \lambda_i u_i u_i^T$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\Sigma u_i = \lambda_i u_i$, we can get by multiply $u_i^T$ on the right sides
$$
\Sigma u_i u_i^T = \lambda_i u_iu_i^T, \quad i=1, \ldots, D.
$$
Now, let us sum up $D$ equations above, which leads to 
$$\Sigma \sum_i u_i u_i^T =  \sum_i \lambda_i u_iu_i^T.$$
Let $U=[u_1, \ldots, u_D]$, a column-binded matrix from $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^D$. If $u_i$'s are **orthonormal** (i.e. $\sum_i u_i u_i^T=U U^T = I$), we now conclude $$\sum_i \lambda_i u_iu_i^T = \Sigma \sum_i u_i u_i^T=\Sigma.$$

As *whuber* suggested, the eigenvectors should satisfy orthonormality, not just orthogonality. OP would be better to check this condition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 -- but your argument is a little incomplete.  Orthonormality of the $u_i$ does not (in itself) imply $UU^\prime = I:$ you also need that there are $D$ of the $u_i.$ I realize this is implicit in your argument, but making it explicit may assist the reader in understanding the key ideas.

Comment: @whuber Agreed. I made an edit based on your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @inmybrain  Thank you for your prompt and useful answer. I think ui(i=1,...,D) is the elements of the vector U. Thus, the transpose of ui is equal to ui,because ui itself is a scalor not a vector. Could you please tell me whether my thoughts is correct?  U is the mean so it is a D*1 vector, and vector x as observation, is also a D*1 vector, the sigma covariance matrix is a D*D matrix, is that right？

Comment: @CiciYang I'm afraid to say it is not. $u_i$ is a $D$-dimensional vector, as $x$ is. $\Sigma$ is a $D \times D$ matrix.

Comment: @@inmybrain  Can you please explain why  (sum uiui(transpose)=UU(transpose)? While using matrix multiplication I can get UU(transpose)=I, I still can not get why sum uiui(transpose)=UU(transpose) exists. I assume that U is a D*D matrix with D column and observations. Is that right? Is there an intuitive way to explain why the sum of the uiui(T)=UU(T)? Thank you.

Comment: @CiciYang It is a simple notation and matrix calculation. I just let $U=[u_1, \ldots, u_D]$ and the calculation is straightforward. I clarified it on the new edit. Please check it :D

Comment: @inmybrain  Sorry to interrupt you again. However if U=[u1,...,ud] then it seems obvious that sum uiui(t)=UU(t) exists.    Then how to get  UU(T)=I?

Comment: It seems that UU(T) will be a number( a row multiplies by a column)

Comment: Maybe U is made up of orthonormal vectors(ui) as columns, therefore U is an orthonormal matrix. As for the properties of the orthonormal matrix, UU(T)=I(reference:Wikipedia:orthogonal matrix)